# X won't start on Debian Testing, Asus TP210S laptop

Tags: debian, xorg, x-server, asus

I installed Debian Testing on an Asus TP210S (ISO file downloaded from https://ftp.acc.umu.se/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/buster_di_alpha4+nonfree/amd64/iso-cd/, not the "edu" one), but `X` won't start.

Here's `Xorg.0.log` from that laptop: https://pastebin.com/u8nJc5pr.

I installed the packages `intel-microcode` and `firmware-misc-nonfree` but it still doesn't start `X`. 
When I query `lsmod|grep -i vga` nothing is returned. The package `xserver-xorg-video-intel` is installed; I report on this because the last time I had this problem on another laptop, it was solved by installing this package.

On running `inxi -Gx` I found out that the driver loaded is modsetting, and it marks `fbdev`, `vesa` as unloaded; when trying to load `vesa` I get the error `FATAL: Module vesa not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.0-4-amd64/`; when I try loading `fbdev` no error is produced but then I run `lsmod|grep fbdev` and nothing appears.

Here's the output of `lsmod|grep -i video`:

```
uvcvideo              118784  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       53248  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              212992  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
media                  45056  2 videodev,uvcvideo
usbcore               290816  4 xhci_hcd,uvcvideo,btusb,xhci_pci
video                  45056  2 asus_wmi,i915
```

Two other things:

1. Whenever I start the laptop, one of the first messages on screen is "Resuming from hibernation", which is quite odd because I just installed the system and haven't enabled hibernation (and I'm not planning on doing it).
2. If left to itself, after about 5 minutes without a login, the laptop will automatically shutdown.
   Any suggestions? I really want to install Testing on this one, specifically because of the more updated version of TeXLive, and because I bought this laptop to use at the office.

Comment: Possible bug: [linux-image-4.19.0-4-amd64: Display manager fails to start or display anything on IvyBridge](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=925555), [linux-image-4.19.0-4-amd64: Please disable kernel-commit d179b88d in drm/i915/fbdev](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=926193). Try kernel 4.19.0-3 or older.

Comment: Thanks. This was a fresh Testing installation, so it had 4.19.0-4, but it has been solved; I'll try installing an older kernel as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone answered this one on the Debian forums: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=141915&p=698118#p698118

The steps are:
1. Log in as root, or boot on single user mode (that's the suggestion in the post).
2. Run 'Xorg -configure'; this generates a file named xorg.conf.new.
3. Copy this file to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf